# AVD does not shows up when build target is higher

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have set the minSdkVersion to 15 and build target to 19 in project properties. I am using Eclipse. I have created 2 AVDs. On with sdk 15 and the other with 19. When I run the project, Eclipse shows me only the AVD which is build with sdk 19. Should it also not show the one with sdk 15 since i have mentioned minSdkVersion as 15? Does this mean my app will not be shown to devices which are running sdk 15 in the market place?

Answer (score 0):

minSDKVersion means the minimum supported version so the app will show up for devices running sdk 15. For me, in Eclipse, all supported emulators show up in android device chooser.

More info : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Nope, its not showing for me. But the moment I edit the AVD15 to AVD19, then it shows up. Not sure, why AVD15 does not shows even if the minSDKVersion is 15